# How to filter array of js objects by an array of boolean values

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array of objects looking like this

```
const data = [
 {
  "Name": "X",
  "is_flagged": false
 },

{
  "Name": "Y",
  "is_flagged": true
 }

 ];
```

and I have a filter array like this

```
 const filters = [true ]   // can also be [true,false]
```

How can I filter the data array based on the filters array values. It should return the records that matches with boolean value/s.

I have tried this way but it doesn't work for boolean values.

```
let result = data.filter(obj => filters.includes(obj.is_flagged))
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Just use a traditional for loop

Comment: it should work just fine. what is the issue you have been facing?

Comment: it works for string values like const filters = ["X"] . But it returns an empty array when the filters are of boolean values like const filters = [true,false].

Comment: I just tried this and it worked: `let res = data.filter(obj => filters.includes(obj["is_flagged"]));`

Comment: `[true].includes(false) // result in false` and hence will filter out accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var records = filters.map((boolVal) => {
  return data.filter((item) => item.is_flagged === boolVal)
})
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue you have been facing, here is the demo :

```js
var data = [ { "Name": "X", "is_flagged": false },{ "Name": 5, "is_flagged": true}];
var filters = [true];

var result = data.filter(val=>filters.includes(val.is_flagged)); // filter out falsy values
console.log(result);  
var filters = [true, false];
var result1 = data.filter(val=>filters.includes(val.is_flagged)); // contains both values
console.log(result1);
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. Thanks!